# Política de uso dos dados em aplicações externas

Tags: debate, suporte, stackexchange

Eu criei uma extensão para *Chrome* e *Opera* que faz o mesmo trabalho da barra do *StackExchange* (não estou usando a API do *StackExchange*), que é notificar sobre novos pontos e comentários (inbox). Também é possível ler as últimas mensagens da inbox e ver os novos pontos. O meu único intuito com o software é poder ser notificado rapidamente, mas sem precisar estar no site para isto.

Basicamente, a minha extensão acessa o site `http://stackexchange.com` como se fosse um "ser humano" e "recolhe" os dados do menu do *StackExchange* exibindo diretamente na extensão.

### A extensão faz:

- Mostra "pushs" (soma de novas mensagens com pontos adiquiridos recentemente)
- Exibe o menu *Caixa de Entrada/Inbox*
- Exibe o menu *Realizações/Achievements*
- Está em código aberto em um repositório para colaborações e máxima transparência do funcionamento.

### O que ela **não** faz:

- Não "intercepta" nenhum tipo de dado, tanto do usuário quanto dos sites
- Não salva dados
- Não modifica as páginas (não injeta nada)
- Não requisita autenticação do usuário

### Dúvidas:

- A minha dúvida é, eu posso distribuir pelo [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) e [Opera Add-ons](https://addons.opera.com/en/) esta extensão para uso?
- Isto infringe algum direito do *StackExchange*? Levando em consideração que o meu aplicativo faz requisições á página `http://stackexchange.com`

Comment: Quanto a primeira, creio que sim pois existe [esse addon](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) que é distribuído para [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc) e [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/se-autoreviewcomments/).

Comment: Pode distribuir que não dá nada! E la garantia soy jo! :--) +1k

Comment: Deixa o @Gabe responder e publica a extensão que eu também quero usar :P

Comment: @JorgeB. Pronto http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4075/extensão-para-chrome-e-opera , tem que fazer uma gambiarra pra instalar, mas logo disponibilizo no ChromeWebStore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Após uma breve conversa (breve mesmo) com usuário BrockAdams o mesmo me informou que é permitido criar aplicativos sem a API:

https://stackapps.com/questions/6446/app-without-api-and-legal-issues#comment13977_6446